# How to replace the $content value in transformation?

Tags: xquery, marklogic, marklogic-8, marklogic-9

I need to replace the $content value in my transformation.

```
xquery version "1.0-ml";

module namespace test =
  "http://marklogic.com/rest-api/transform/security-load";

declare function test:transform(
    $context as map:map,
    $params as map:map,
    $content as document-node()
) as document-node()
{       
        let $jsonObj := xdmp:from-json($content)
        let $inputval := "fname,lname"
        let $entity :="holidayDate"
        let $domain :="referenceData"


        let $uri := xdmp:apply(
            xdmp:function(xs:QName("createUri"), "/wdsUtils.sjs"),
            $jsonObj,
            $inputval)


        let $root := xdmp:apply(
            xdmp:function(xs:QName("addMetaData"), "/wdsUtils.sjs"),
            $entity,
            $domain,
            $jsonObj)

        let $output := $root    

        return map:put($context,"uri",$uri),
        document { $output }
};
```

I need to change the $content value with $root value and return it. I was trying to return $root directly but it didn't work, I was getting invalid document error.

[image]

Comment: Can you post the error you are getting?

Comment: updated the question with error, please check.

Comment: Error seems to be : `undefined variable $output`. But it is there. Did you maybe forget the variable while uploading the transformation? I'd re-upload the transformation and try again.

Comment: when i try to return $content it works fine, but when i try to return $output its not working.

Comment: should i typecast $output to something else and then return??

Comment: The error message says `$output` is not even definied, so typecasting will probably not help. Does returning `$root` work?

Comment: No, returning $content is only working.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

The problem is that `$output` is scoped to the FLWOR statement, but you're referring to it outside of that statement. See the parentheses in the `return` below.

```
xquery version "1.0-ml";

module namespace test = "http://marklogic.com/rest-api/transform/security-load";

declare function test:transform(
    $context as map:map,
    $params as map:map,
    $content as document-node()
) as document-node()
{       
    let $jsonObj := xdmp:from-json($content)
    let $inputval := "fname,lname"
    let $entity :="holidayDate"
    let $domain :="referenceData"

    let $uri := 
        xdmp:apply(
            xdmp:function(xs:QName("createUri"), "/wdsUtils.sjs"),
            $jsonObj,
            $inputval
        )

    let $root := 
        xdmp:apply(
            xdmp:function(xs:QName("addMetaData"), "/wdsUtils.sjs"),
            $entity,
            $domain,
            $jsonObj
        )

    let $output := $root    

    return (
        map:put($context,"uri",$uri),
        document { $output }
    )
};
```

Comment: Even when I return just $root, it's not working. Why?`return (
        map:put($context,"uri",$uri),
       $root 
    )`

Comment: Because the return type from the function is `document-node()` (see the "as" clause). Looks like `$root` is not a document node, hence the need to wrap the result in `document { }`.

Comment: How can I convert $root to document node?

Comment: Hey, finally found a solution!! `return (map:put($context,"uri",$uri), document { xdmp:to-json($contentWithMetadata) })` I was missing "()" brackets

Comment: `xdmp:to-json` returns a `document-node()`; you need either the `document { }` or the call to `xdmp:to-json`, but not both.